# Query to return Model X based on the nested resources Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following models:

```
Thread (id, title, timestamps)
ThreadParticipant (id, thread_id, user_id, read(boolean), timestamps)
Comment (id, thread_id, user_id)
```

How can a query be constructed where it returns: All Threads where the most recent Thread Comment (Thread.comment.first) is equal to the current_user?

... Return Threads where the last comment.user_id == current_user.id?

Ideas?

Comment: Let me know if the question is to confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like [Untested code]:

```
Thread.find_by_sql(["Select * from Threads where ((select user_id from comments where threads.id = comments.thread_id ORDER by created_at DESC LIMIT 1) = ?)", current_user.id ])
```

OR give this a try (not sure if asking for distinct will automatically pick first one but I'm guessing it should):

```
 Thread.find(:all, :joins => :comments , :select => ["distinct threads.id"], :conditions => ["comments.user_id = ?", current_user.id])
```

Comment: Thanks but do you think there's a way to not resort to writing straight SQL? Trying to avoid that to be rails friendly

Comment: added another line. BTW, there is nothing wrong with using SQL, you can also always put it in the Model and wrap it with a method so it still looks elegant in the controller. Sometimes you might be able to write more efficient SQL that Rails will automatically do for you.